# How can I make tap work on mobile device with jquery

Tags: jquery, mobile, tap

Could somebody shed some light on why the "tap" on a mobile device is not caught with the following code:

```
$(document).on('tap click', '.custom-menu-button a', function(event){            // when they click on the popup element
            $('.popup-overlay').addClass('show');
        });
```

touchstart works but it has this delay, so the user needs to keep his finger on the button for a while for it to work.

Comment: Unless you are using jQuery Mobile (and you should not), `tap` is not a native event

Comment: using `.on('click'...)` should be enough to get it to work on mobile. How does your HTML look, why isn't a normal click working for you?

Comment: Thanks for getting back,  on('click') is not working in Chrome, it only works in Safari and Firefox. Why should I not use JQuery Mobile?